# Exchange 365 Disclaimer AD Attributes

Tags: active-directory, attributes, exchange-server

I've been trying to customize a disclaimer Mail Flow Rule on O365 Exchange to pull Active Directory information.

My current code is as follows:

```
<div style="font-size:11pt; font-family: 'Tahoma; color:gray">
</br>
 %%displayname%% | %%department%% |%%title%%</br>
 </br>
 <b>COMPANY NAME</b></br> 
%%street%% %%city%%, %%zipcode%%</br>
 </br> 
D: %%phoneNumber%%</br> 
C: %%mobileNumber%%</br>
T: %%homePhoneNumber%%</br>
F: %%faxNumber%%</br>
E: %%email%%</br>
 </br>
 www.COMPANYWEBSITE.com
```

Output is as follows:

```
Testing Signature | Tech Support | Testing Account

**COMPANY NAME**
Street Address
City, State ZIP

D: 999.888.7777
C: 111.222.3333
T: 
F: 
E: Tsignature@companydomain.com

www.CompanyWebsite.com
```

Both homePhoneNumber and faxNumber are not pulling from their respective AD fields... Any idea where these attributes actually pull from?

Found attributes online here:

https://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/active-directory-data-in-email-signatures/

Any dirrection would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

hyper_sloth

Comment: > PhoneNumber : telephoneNumber, Fax : facsimileTelephoneNumber.